# Web deployment tool

Tags: deployment, msdeploy

I would like to know if in IIS manager, when I export an application, there is a way to save components selected so, when I export next time, to select them by default (like appHostConfig). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible today, if you are constantly using it you should consider using the command line instead that will easily allow you to save those in an external file and run them as frequently as needed without having to specify everything again.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too :)